# External Login WebAPI2 MVC5

Tags: security, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api2, token

I need to use a 3rd party token as a way to authenticate. I'm getting the token in the home controller and need to be able to send it on to my WebAPI controllers (It's an SPA application using Backbone). Is there a way of doing this?

EDIT:

Relevant code:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string projectId, int companyId, bool isCompanyAdmin)
        {
                // if not a valid user return error
                var validate = new Validate().ValidateContext(HttpContext,
                   "Key", "Secret");
                if (!validate.IsValidated) return View(Constants.ValidationFailed);


      // The info validated, so now I can set it to authorized
      // put code here for doing it


        //Get the model for the user
        try
        {
            var model = ConvertToVM(_smsRepository.GetCompany(companyId, projectId));
        }
        catch (ProviderIncompatibleException)
        {
            // connection string wrong
            return View(Constants.ConnectionFailed);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // catch all
            return View(Constants.DatabaseError);
        }
        //create and send through the view model that determines what view the user will get
        return View(model);
    }
```

Ok I put in the index method on the Home Controller. Like I said, we make a call to a third party API passing in the context, the client key, and the client secret to verify our identity. Could I just add a Bearer token in the home controller? Or otherwise pass the http context to OWiN and use some custom logic to add the token if validate.IsValidated is true? It needs to be something that works with WebAPI.

Comment: Try backbone-login project https://github.com/alexanderscott/backbone-login

Comment: Pllease add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok added what I have.